# MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI returns empty cursor

Tags: android, mediastore

I have code to get all images from external by `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` and internal by same (but internal instead of external)

In my device android version 7.0 all images in external and internal returned by external cursor and like question title internal returns empty cursor and i am 100% that i have lots of images in internal

**Big Strange Prob**
that same code works fine with another device android version 5.1 internal returns internal images and external returns it's own imgs so where is the problem i don't get it ....

how same code works differently on 2 real devices(no emulators here)

**Code of both cursors is below**

```
cursorEx = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, null, null, DATE_DESC_SORT_ORDER);

cursorIn = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, null, null, DATE_DESC_SORT_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you did not asked for permission in android 7. Its mandatory! You can either ask for permission, or target a SDK less than 22.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ProfileActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ProfileActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
        }

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ProfileActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
        // app-defined int constant that should be quite unique

        return;
    }else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                "Selecione a foto "), select_image_code);
    }
```

Comment: certainly i asked for permission otherwise it would throw an exception ... sorry but that is not the solution .. Thanks